# Pylint unable to "from X.Y import Z", but "from X import Y" works?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm using Visual Studio Code with Python externs (Python 3.8).

The following statement got a pylint error with message of "Unable to import 'a.b'pylint(import-error)"

```
from a.b import c
```

However, the following one doesn't have pylint error?

```
from a import b
x = b.c
```

Comment: It look like a bug in pylint but it's basically impossible to understand what's wrong if you're hiding the underlying code. (We can't see what pylint parse badly)

Comment: If `a.b` isn’t a module, the error is correct and it’s not surprising that the working version is also correct.